# Qt Creator indexer doesn't recognize "Window" or "StackView"

Tags: qt, import, qml, environment

I think this is an issue with the indexer: my environment doesn't recognize `Window` or `StackView`, or even the two `import` statements. Everything compiles, builds, and runs fine.

I've poked around in `Projects > Manage Kits`, and changing the Kit actually fixes the issue, but it's on a kit for a board I'm no longer using. I've looked through the differences on the kits, and matched them up, but still nothing changed.

Which setting do I change to allow my environment to recognize these keywords?

Comment: *Everything compiles, builds, and runs fine...* If it doesnt recognise import, how the way it works fine ?

Comment: I've restarted my PC and it's now working. If it occurs again I'll update this question with images